# Accidentally deleted the SSL key from EC2 Ubuntu. How can I restore

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2

I have purchased a SSL certificate for my website. As an initial process, I have created a CSR and KEY file and presented it to the certification provider.  Upon receiving the certification, I have copied all the files including the .key, .csr, .crt files into a folder by name certs.

While removing unnecessary files from the drive, I accidentally deleted the certs folder also. I have the .crt files in my local machine, Can i retrieve the .key file and the cert folder.

I tried using extundelete and used the following command.

```
sudo extundelete --restore-directory /home/ubuntu/certs /dev/sda1
```

I don't understand the /dev/sda1 part. Is there any chance where I could retrieve the files?  The folder was in EC2 Ubuntu instance.

Comment: The problem is I am yet to enable the ssl

Comment: The problem is you will have to start again with a new key pair if you don't have a backup. More care required next time. Off topic.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a question about programming at all; more about server administration.

Comment: Now I understand its not a question about programming, but when I deleted the key file I had a panic attack and didn't know what to do.  Hence raised a false alarm.  I got this resolved by creating another key and taking a new certificate from the vendor.  Many thanks for your support and apologies for raising a false alarm.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the old certificate and get new free one via https://letsencrypt.org/